# Flutter - Using timer to change color of element in gridView() as a sequence

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, timer, widget

I'm creating a mini-game in my app, which should consist of a grid of 3x3 buttons, which will flash randomly in sequence one-by-one and the user has to recreate it.
I managed to create the buttons with `GridView()` and set up a timer, but right now I'm struggling with changing the color property of the button inside the `GridView()`. Which got me thinking If I'm using `GridView()` correctly.

I want to change the color of a button multiple times via `Timer` in a random sequence and then the user should recreate it. Can I do it with a timer and `GridView()`or is there an easier way of doing this?
(My mini-game should be similar to [Among us Reactor task](https://among-us.fandom.com/wiki/Start_Reactor))

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Challenge extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChallengeState createState() => _ChallengeState();
}

class _ChallengeState extends State<Challenge> {
  Timer timer;
  Map userData = {};
  int indexSaved;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer timer) {
        print('hey');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    timer.cancel();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    userData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    print(userData);

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              // mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: List.generate(9, (index) {
                return Center(
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    color: Colors.blueGrey[300],
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                    splashColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      indexSaved = index;
                      print(indexSaved);
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT 21/10/2020:
I created a little function that should generate sequences and I'm launching them inside the timer. I worked on the answers which I got and tried to redo them so I could use them in my use case.

The color I'm changing with:

```dart
color: indexWithColor == index
       ? Colors.indigo
       : Colors.blueGrey[300],
```

which works great.

(The snippet was edited)

```dart
  List<int> correctValues = [];
  int indexWithColor;
  int indexDisplayed = 0;

  void generateNewLevel() {
    final random = new Random(seed);
    correctValues.add(random.nextInt(9));
    timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), (Timer timer) {
      setState(() {
        indexWithColor = correctValues[indexDisplayed];
        // print('Index color ' + indexWithColor.toString());
        indexDisplayed++;
        if (indexDisplayed == correctValues.length) {
          new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
            setState(() {
              indexWithColor = null;
              indexDisplayed = 0;
            });
            timer.cancel();
          });
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Right now I'm using a button to generate a new level (later I will change it when I solve this problem). It works, but I have issues with it.

1. Users cannot distinguish if the button is pressed twice (right now its color is pressed for a bit longer).

<strike>2. It seems like the buttons have a bit delay when they are launching. It's not exact 500ms and the sleep is really messy.</strike>

<strike>3. The first level (with a one-long sequence is not visible as it gets changed as soon as the timer is canceled.</strike>

Is there a better option?

EDIT: 21/10/2020 12:00pm

I solved the second and third problems with edited timer, so it kinda works right now, but isn't there a better way?
Check the edited snippet. -^

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just randomly change the color of your button this is one way to do it:
(Edited: to make sure that same index isn't selected twice in a row)

```
final rng = Random();
int indexWithColor;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer timer) {
    setState(() {
      int tempIndex;
      do {
        tempIndex = rng.nextInt(9);
      } while (tempIndex == indexWithColor);
      indexWithColor = tempIndex;
    });
  });
}
```

and in your MaterialButton:

```
color: indexWithColor == index
                    ? Colors.red
                    : Colors.blueGrey[300],
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I managed to get it working and it's a huge step forward. I generating a sequence of flashing buttons and then wait for the user input. I created a little function (check edit) and I guess this won't work as it needs to regenerate. Right now It should just go to infinity and I'll do timer pause waiting for user input.

Comment: Great! Yeah obviously my suggesting was not the finished product, just to kick you forward a bit. Accept the answer if it was helpful so this question can be considered closed. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, I'm just struggling with timers as I cannot reset the state of the colored button. The process that you suggested is for random numbers, but I need to "re-run" the sequence multiple times with just one additional blink in the array. I don't know If I should add a timer (as I did) or I can just let the timer run the sequence (which I'm currently trying to do, but I don't know how to correctly reset it to the previous state).
I created the function which should generate levels, meaning that It will run only once at the beginning in init and then with each completed sequence.

Comment: Also, it is possible that the index is selected 2 times in a row so I really need to reset the color and not recolor the next item.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with a Timer. But you need to expand your list with a boolean field which is `isIndexSaved`.

```
class NewModel {
    int index;
    bool isIndexSaved;
}
```

Then you need to generate a new list with newModel and set isIndexSaved to true when onPressed(). And the color of the MaterialButton should look like:

```
   color: newModel.isIndexSaved 
          ? Colors.red[300], // desired color
          : Colors.blueGrey[300],
```